# Losing click event after recreating elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm removing table **tbody** set and inserting new ones but I'm loosing **click** event on chekcbox. How can I solve this issue?

I went through append(), clone() but failed to apply to my code so for that reason I created a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/678CP/) which has everything.

Please tell me what I need to do.

Thanks in advance.

[JSFIDDLE - CODE IS HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/678CP/)

**JQUERY:**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.add-selected').on("click",function() {
       alert('hello');
    });

    $('#removeAndAdd').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var output = '';
        output += '<tbody class="filter-rows">';
        output += '<tr class="filter">';
        output += '<td><input type="checkbox" id="c-1" class="add-selected" /></td>';
        output += '<td>1</td>';
        output += '</tr>';
        output += '</tbody>';

        output += '<tbody class="filter-rows">';
        output += '<tr class="filter">';
        output += '<td><input type="checkbox" id="c-2" class="add-selected" /></td>';
        output += '<td>2</td>';
        output += '</tr>';
        output += '</tbody>';

        $('.filter-rows').empty();
        $('#add-new-table tbody:last').after(output);
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
      <table id="add-new-table" border="1px">
        <thead>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>SKU</th>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Lbel</td>
                <td>011</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tbody class="filter-rows">
            <tr class="filter">
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="c-1" class="add-selected" /></td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tbody class="filter-rows">
            <tr class="filter">
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="c-2" class="add-selected" /></td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tbody class="filter-rows">
            <tr class="filter">
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="c-3" class="add-selected" /></td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>

<br />
<span id='removeAndAdd'>Click me to Remove all first and Add new rows</span>
```

Comment: I could be wrong but I think the problem is you are trying to use click events in jQuery on dynamically created elements. I believe you may need to look into binding these events with the jQuery .on() event.

Comment: You're right they are created in a loop. I looked into jQuery .on() event but to be honest I'm bad with jQuery so I didn't know what to change.

Comment: @RyanBeaulieu You are right. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There some bad practices here. Firstly the fixed version:

http://jsfiddle.net/678CP/5/

```
$('#add-new-table').on('change', 'input', function() {
   alert('hello');
});

$('#removeAndAdd').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var rows = $('#add-new-table .filter-rows');

    rows.first().add(rows.last()).remove();
});
```

1. I am going to assume you need to make a new `tbody` for every row - otherwise remove it.
2. Why re-create the whole table? I am assuming you don't need to, if you do the code needs some changes.
3. Why wait for domLoad? I have change it to onDomReady (fiddle settings)
4. A clickable element should be an anchor `<a>` with an href
5. I know this is just a demo but I am hoping you don't mix double and single quotes in your html and javascript and that you don't use IDs everywhere

How it works:

By using the second parameter of jQuery's [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) we have created an [event delegate](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). This means that the event is placed on the table itself `#add-new-table` and it is listening for changes to any inputs inside the table. So it is one single event and it doesn't care if stuff inside is updated/removed etc. It is also more efficient.

And a small explanation of `var rows = $('#add-new-table .filter-rows'); rows.first().add(rows.last()).remove();`:

"Get all the filter rows and store that. Then select the first row and add the last row to that selection, finally remove them"